# how to prove that $abc$ and $cba$ do not necessarily have the same order?

Tags: group-theory, examples-counterexamples

Let $a$, $b$ and $c$ be elements of a group $G$, how can I prove that $abc$ and $cba$ do not necessarily have the same order?

I know that this cannot hold for abelian groups, but unsure how to start otherwise.

Also, it is impossible to find a counterexample if we change the order to $cab$, see here: [Let $G$ be a group. Show that $\forall a, b, c \in G$, the elements $abc, bca, cab$ have the same order.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2238562).

Comment: Pick a non-abelian group and fool around with the orders of some combinations. To prove what you want, one such example is enough.

Comment: There are examples in the smallest non-Abelian group.

Comment: I got it! Thanks a lot.

Comment: I don't understand closing ancient questions. I'd rather they were improved. So I've added a line in giving some sort of attempt.

Comment: Selecting $a=b^{-1}c^{-1}$ points at a way of finding examples.

Answer (score 4):

Consider the quaternion group,
$$ H_{8} = \langle \pm 1,\pm i,\pm j, \pm k \mid i^2=j^2=k^2=ijk=-1 \rangle. $$
Then $ ijk = -1 $ has order $2$ (obviously, since $(-1)^2 = 1$), but $jik = -ijk = 1 $ has order $1$.

(To see this, note that $ij=(ijk)(-k)=k$, but $ji = -ji(ijk) = -k = -ji $.)

Comment: Ahh I see... Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Try the dihedral group $D_4$ of eight elements.

Comment: I don't understand the logic of answering an old question whilst simultaneously putting it on CRUDE and voting to close it!

Comment: @user1729: Well, I don't know. Right now I don't care. My very own hardback copy of Dummit & Foote has just arrived! $\ddot\smile$